# NSURLSession object has to be retained

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I created a NSURLSession object but did not retain it

```
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlRequest]];

    [task resume];
}
```

then I implemented the system delegates:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    ....
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(nonnull NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(nonnull NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler
{
    ....
    completionHandler(....);
}

....
```

the code works fine without any issues now.  But I am wondering that can the session object be deallocated before system call the delegates?  If the session object is deallocated, what will happen to the delegates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously it will not deallocate as long as you have the strong reference in `session`.

But I guess your concern is if `session` is a local variable and it goes out of scope. The documentation is less than clear but from testing I have found the session stays around with some form of self reference to finish it's work.

It is what happens then that becomes interesting. If you have lost your reference to the session like if it was only local then I believe is no way to find it again. This could be a memory leak, it stays on forever but untouchable. I'm not quite sure. However that is not what you want to do.

Sometimes you want that to add more tasks to the same session, in which case you need to hold on to it with a property or something so you can get to it persistently.

Sometimes you want it to go away once the task is complete. This can be acomplished with the method `-finishTasksAndInvalidate` which you call directly after `-resume` in your code. See documentation, it will complete the tasks started and then drop delegates and itself eventually.

In general what you want to do is to ensure you use the session permanently or that you somewhere call one of the `invalidate` methods, see "managing the session" in the class documentation.